# Webdriver.io: combining customCommand and execute and maximum call stack

Tags: node.js, selenium, extjs4, webdriver-io

I got an RuntimeError: unknown error: Maximum call stack size exceeded from a simple execute combined with a customCommand
Here is my code:

```
var ExtQ = function(name){
    var ret = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('textfield[name='+name+']');
    return ret[0];
};


browser.addCommand('getIdFromExtName', function(name){
    return this.execute(ExtQ, name).then(function(ret){
        //console.log(obj.value);
        //console.log(ret);
        return ret.value.inputId;
    });

});
```

I use it like this:

```
return this.getIdFromExtName(name).then(function(id){
       return this.setValue("#"+id, value).then(function(){
              return this.keys('Enter');
       });
});
```

My error:

```
Failed: unknown error: Maximum call stack size exceeded
running chrome
RuntimeError: unknown error: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

I have no idea of how I made that much calls.
Also my ExtJS code work perfectly on my chrome DevTools console.
Any clues guys?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it. The object I was returning from ExtJS was way too big so instead I just extracted the data I needed.